# Setuptools: Installing packages with overlapping layouts

Tags: python, setuptools, pylint

I have two packages with a common hierarchy. Something like:

`org.team.foo`:

```
org/
    __init__.py
    team/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
            baz.py
```

`org.team.bar`:

```
org/
    __init__.py
    team/
        __init__.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
            qux.py
```

`setup.py` looks like this:
`org.team.foo`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='foopack',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages()
      )
```

`org.team.bar`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='barpack',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages()
      )
```

I would like to distribute `org.team.foo` and `org.team.bar` as different distributions. I know the recommended way is to make `org` and `team` namespace directories. Unfortunately, `pylint`, which is a big part of our continuous integration workflow does not recognize namespace packages. I am wondering if I can just distribute these separately and install them on top of each other. I tried this (`sudo pip install foopack && sudo pip install barpack`) and it seems to produce the following in the install location:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
    org/
        __init__.py
        team/
            __init__.py
            foo/
                __init__.py
                baz.py
            bar/
                __init__.py
                quz.py
```

This seems to work as expected, except that if I uninstall `foopack`, `org/__init__.py` and `org/team/__init__.py` are uninstalled as well. This is not something I expect in my workflow, so I am ok with this.

Are there any other downsides to this? Is there something I am not considering, or an alternative I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install two packages with common hierarchy is really usage of namespace package.

If your CI server does not handle them, then you shall fix it on CI side, otherwise the CI server will force you to break your product (what is likely not the intended result of using CI server).